# Simplifying $1-3^{-x}+(2\times 3^{-x-1})$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am trying to simplify this: $1-3^{-x}+(2\times 3^{-x-1})$

Results I have been finding are that it can simplify to $1-3^{-x-1}$

I am not sure how it can conclude to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can simplify $$1- 3^{-x} + 2*3^{-x-1} = 1 + 3^{-x}\left(2*3^{-1} - 1\right) 
= 1 + 3^{-x}\left(\dfrac23 - 1\right) = 1 - 3^{-x-1} $$

Answer (score 1):

With $y=3^{-x-1}$ so that $3^{-x}=3y$, your expression is 
$$
1-3y+2\times y=1-3y+2y=1-y=1-3^{-x-1}.
$$
The substitution for $y$ may be an overkill in this case but it can aid in more complicated problems.

Answer (score 1):

$\displaystyle 1-3^{-x}+(2\times 3^{-x-1})=\frac{3-3^{-x}(3-2)}{3}=1-3^{-x-1}$